# Why is my QuickSort overflowing?

Tags: c++, quicksort, partitioning

I'm trying to implement `QuickSort()` using random pivot

When I'm not randomizing pivot, and choosing it to be A[0] everything works fine,
but when I implement the randomization things are going crazy.

Partition:

```
int Partition(int A[], int left, int right, int pivot = 0)
{
    swap(A[left], A[pivot]);

    int temp = right;

    while (pivot != temp)
    {
        // make a swap if needed
        if (A[pivot] > A[temp] && temp > pivot || A[temp] > A[pivot] && temp < pivot)
        {
            // swap both data and index
            swap(A[pivot], A[temp]);
            swap(pivot, temp);
        }

        // advance the temp towards pivot
        if (temp < pivot)
            temp++;
        else
            temp--;
    }
return pivot;
}
```

QuickSort:

```
void QuickSort(int A[], int left, int right)
{
    int pivot;

    if (left < right) {
        // randomize pivot
        srand(time(NULL));
        pivot = rand() % (right - left + 1);

        // partition and call quicksort
        pivot = Partition(A, left, right, pivot);
        QuickSort(A, left, pivot - 1);
        QuickSort(A, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with, don't call `srand` in `QuickSort`, as it will be called many times a given second you will get the same seed for *all* those calls, leading to `rand` returning the same value all the time. Call int only once, at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: That was it @JoachimPileborg, it solved the overflow. But for some reason the sorting isn't correct.

Comment: If it sort correct vs A[0], but not vs rand pivot element,a quick patch is to do a swap between the initial element and random element. then call partition as before, with pivot vs the new zero element.

Comment: Start with a small array, and step through the code line by line in a debugger. Then when you shown this to the professor throw it away and start using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Is right meant to be inclusive, or beyond end of array?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett The end of the array itself

Comment: Because most people take array indices to be inclusive of first, and exclusive of second, but here you seemto be inclusive of second.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett What do you mean by 'inclusive of second'?

Comment: an array A[6] has element 0..5 inclusive. Most c++ people provide/expect the arguments provided to a function for the upper/2nd index to be beyond the end ie, 6 not 5.

Comment: btw, your partition doesnt work. You should focus your testing on it.

Comment: it does work now, I needed to set `pivot = left;` after the swap atthe beginning of `partition()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an issue:

```
pivot = rand() % (right - left + 1);
```

needs to be

```
pivot = left + rand() % (right - left + 1);
```

Comment: You are right, since I send the whole array to the recursion I need to let the pivot choose a number between my current left and the end of the array.